# Replace standard search with federated search results

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

I would like to know if there is a way to give the 'Federated Results' (FR) web part the same look and feel as the 'Search Core Results' (SCR) web part.

For instance, the SCR shows me how many results are found depending on the search query where FR does not.
Another example is SCR has a 'next' button at the end if it's result page where FR shows only a 'more results' button.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the rendering for SCR to render like FR or the other way arround. 
You can add the total count for FR, the schema of opensearch does contain it so it should work: http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1

Follow this article to see what xml both webparts render: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546985.aspx - there should be one tag .